# Adding an object to an array of objects which is in another class

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have looked at a few forum posts and I know java is Pass by Value. However I am still a bit confused on this. So my question is if StoryFragment has an array of annotations and I would like to add an annotation into that array through another class which has an addAnnotation method then would my code below work? In StoryFragment I am using a getter method to receive the array of annotations.

```
public class StoryFragmentController {

public void addAnnotation(Annotation annotation, StoryFragment storyFragment){
    storyFragment.getAnnotations().add(annotation);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only one way to find out.

Comment: Yes of course, that works fine.  Confused what you would think it has to be with pass-by-value?

Comment: Is there another more efficient way?

Comment: You could just add the annotation directly instead of going through a method call.

Comment: Why do you think that this is not efficient?